# Example of SAX XML Parser for iPhone in iOS

Tags: xml, objective-c, xmlparser, ios, iphone

Привет всем!

Столкнулся с XML парсером для iOS. Не могу разобраться с тем как он функционирует. И не понятно совсем что делать с "CDATA" Мне нужно отпарсить и отобразить на дисплее эти данные:

```
 ![CDATA[ Coca Cola ]]                 >>>>>>>      Coca Cola
 ![CDATA[ 2 Liter ]];                  >>>>>>>      2 Liter
 <origin id="13">Austria</origin>      >>>>>>>      Austria
 <name>Energy kcal</name>              >>>>>>>      Energy kcal
 <value>42</value>                     >>>>>>>      42
 <unit>kcal</unit>                     >>>>>>>      kcal
 <name>Energy kj</name>                >>>>>>>      Energy kj
 <value>180</value>                    >>>>>>>      180
 <unit>kj</unit>                       >>>>>>>      kj
```

Это мой XML file, который я должен парсить:

```
<userfood_overview xmlns="http://www.wikifood.lu" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.wikifood.lu userfood.xsd">
<hits>1</hits>
<startAt>0</startAt>
<userfood>
<id>866381</id>
<ean>5449000000286</ean>
<name>
    <![CDATA[ Coca Cola ]]>
</name>
<modification>2012-06-11</modification>
<info1>
    <![CDATA[ 2 Liter ]]>
</info1>
    <origin id="13">Austria</origin>
<brand>
<id>79757</id>
<name>
<![CDATA[ Coca-Cola ]]>
</name>
</brand>
<contents>
<![CDATA[ 2 ]]>
</contents>
<unit id="1">Litre</unit>
<expiration>
<![CDATA[ 2012-11-15 ]]>
</expiration>
<nutrition_facts>
<nutrition_fact id="Per_100_g_ml">
<name>per 100</name>
<value>ml</value>
<unit/>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="EnergyKcal">
    <name>Energy kcal</name>
    <value>42</value>
    <unit>kcal</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="EnergyKjoule">
    <name>Energy kj</name>
    <value>180</value>
    <unit>kj</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Protein">
<name>Protein</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Carbohydrate">
<name>Carbohydrate</name>
<value>10.60</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Sugar"> 
<name>Sugar</name>
<value>10.60</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Polypols">
<name>Polypols</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Starch">
<name>Starch</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Fat">
<name>Fat</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Saturates">
<name>Saturates</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="MonoUnsaturates">
<name>Mono-unsaturates</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="PolyUnsaturates">
<name>Polyunsaturates</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>g</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Cholosterol">
<name>Cholosterol</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>mg</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Fibre">
<name>Fibre</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>mg</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
<nutrition_fact id="Sodium">
<name>Sodium</name>
<value>0</value>
<unit>mg</unit>
</nutrition_fact>
</nutrition_facts>
<medias>
<media id="15564" src="/getUserfoodMedia?id=15564"/>
<media_t id="15564" src="/getUserfoodMedia?id=15564&thumbnail=true"/>
<media id="15565" src="/getUserfoodMedia?id=15565"/>
<media_t id="15565" src="/getUserfoodMedia?id=15565&thumbnail=true"/>
<media id="15563" src="/getUserfoodMedia?id=15563"/>
<media_t id="15563" src="/getUserfoodMedia?id=15563&thumbnail=true"/>
<media id="15561" src="/getUserfoodMedia?id=15561"/>
<media_t id="15561" src="/getUserfoodMedia?id=15561&thumbnail=true"/>
</medias>
<food_notes/>
<category id="0501006" delimiter=":">
<![CDATA[ Lemonades/carbonated drinks ]]>
</category>
<insertion>2012-06-10</insertion>
<editable>true</editable>
</userfood>
```

</userfood_overview>

Из документации на: [XML Parsing Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002264-BCIIJEEH)  мне не совсем понятно, что нужно делать. Вот то, что у меня есть сейчас:

```
#pragma mark *** NSXMLParserDelegate ***

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    // do preparation for loading data from XML
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
     [parser release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    //analyze parseError
    [parser release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
     NSLog(@"elementName %@", elementName); // current parsing element
// specify type of data to be saved in method below
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
     NSLog(@"value of element %@", string); // value for current parsing element
     // save data to some ivar for future use (displaying)
}
```

Может у кого-то есть link или пример, или tutorial? Поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я юзаю [KISSxml](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML)
Самый няшний, что нашел. Но так то парсеров до пупа. Все юзают либу libxml.
Там без примеров все понятно.

Comment: Да, но все таки это ничего не обьясняет касательно стандартного NSXML Parser. И мне не понятно какие переменные есть. Или что конкретно отвечает за что

Comment: Это, как минимум объясняет, что стандартный парсер Какаха. Ручками там все ручками.
Там даже в Экзаплах мозг сломать можно: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html